# getJSON() JavaScript function not called

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

I am trying to transfer data from a jsp file using a json object.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
// action when item file is clicked
$("li span.file").click(function(){

// get the ID
alert(' Forward the url when clicked WITH ID => ' + $(this).attr('id'));

$.getJSON('BomItemToJSON', function(data) {
    alert('entered getJSON()');
    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
        alert('entered each()');
        var id = item.id;
        var description = item.description;

        alert('description: ' + description);

        formObject = document.forms['itemForm'];
        formObject.elements['itemId'].value = id;
        formObject.elements['itemDescription'].value = description;

        alert('done with javascirpt');
    });
});

});
```

This is my Servlet which should be called by JavaScript:

```
public class BomItemToJSON extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "xxx")
public EntityManager em;

@Resource
UserTransaction utx;

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getCanonicalName());


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("bom item to json servlet has been called.");
    try {
        utx.begin();
    } catch (NotSupportedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    BomHandling bh = new BomHandling(em, utx);

    BomItem item = bh.getBomItem(63788);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(item);

    System.out.println("Json: " + json);

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().write(json);

    try {
        utx.commit();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (RollbackException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicMixedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (HeuristicRollbackException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SystemException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

This is my web.xml which maps the Servlet:

```
 <servlet>
  <display-name>BomItemToJSON</display-name>
  <servlet-name>BomItemToJSON</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.xxx.servlets.BomItemToJSON</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>BomItemToJSON</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/BomItemToJSON</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

When I click on the item, I get the alert saying "Forward the url when clicked with id". But it seems like that the getJSON() function is not called. Why?

Comment: Does the specified URL `'BomItemToJSON'` actually exist? In case yes, what does it return? Do you get errors in your JS console?

Comment: In any modern browser, open the debugging tools and look at the "Network" tab or similar. You'll probably see a 404 error or similar, which would indicate a problem with the URL mapping, or a 500 error, which would indicate a problem with the servlet. If you see neither, you should see the response data, which may help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual problem, but why are you returning JSON with the content type `text/plain`? The correct content type for JSON is [`application/json`](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627). (I say it's unrelated because `getJSON` will ignore the content type and try to interpret the result as JSON. But as you're setting the content type explicitly, may as well set it correctly.)

Comment: I didnt know about this debugging tools, thanks for this. And indeed, you were right with the location. I have defined an absolute path now and it is triggered ( $.getJSON('<%= application.getContextPath() %>/BomItemToJSON', function(data) {). If you write this as an answer I will accpept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few debugging tips to find whats missing:

1. Use Firebug for Firefox (I still find the other equivalents less good)
2. Use console.log("text") instead of alerts, they are not as disruptive. Remember to remove them / comment them out as they break in IE etc.
3. Use the debugger in the script tab in Firebug to check that your code reaches the getJson function in the first place. Also you can debug the callback function.
4. Use the net tab to see if your /BomItemToJSON url is called and what response is given to the browser.

Also, I personally like to use the $.ajax function only in jQuery and not their shorthands.